# Aggregate Over Multiple Columns with Multiple Data Types in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame such that the variables in the first n columns are the same over, for instance, 2 rows and I would like to aggregate over the renaming columns that are of type float. Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=[[1,2,np.nan,'string', 100, 200],[1,2,np.nan,'string',102,202],[1,2,5,0.5,1000,2000],[1,2,5,0.5,1002,2002]]


pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['Var1','Var2','Var3','Var4','Var5','Var6'])

   Var1  Var2  Var3    Var4  Var5  Var6
0     1     2   NaN  string   100   200
1     1     2   NaN  string   102   202
2     1     2   5.0     0.5  1000  2000
3     1     2   5.0     0.5  1002  2002
```

So in this data frame, I would like to find the average of `Var5` and `Var6` over each 2 rows. The intended output would be the following:

```py
   Var1  Var2  Var3    Var4  Var5  Var6
0     1     2   NaN  string   101   201
1     1     2   5.0     0.5  1001  2001
```

Is there a way to do this given data types of the same features are not consistent? For instance, `Var3` can be `nan` and a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
dc=dict(zip(df.columns,np.where(df.dtypes!='object','mean','first')))
df.groupby(df.index//2).agg(dc)
```

Output:

```
   Var1  Var2  Var3    Var4  Var5  Var6
0     1     2   NaN  string   101   201
1     1     2   5.0     0.5  1001  2001
```

---

**Details**:

*To get the dictionary with the functions:*

When a column has a mixed types of values or all the type of the values is string, the `dtype` of the column is `object`, so you can mask the columns to get the "non-dtype-object" columns, and with `np.where` put the function `mean` to the columns different to object and `first` to the others:

```
df.dtypes
#Var1      int64
#Var2      int64
#Var3    float64
#Var4     object
#Var5      int64
#Var6      int64
dtype: object

np.where(df.dtypes!='object','mean','first')
#['mean' 'mean' 'mean' 'first' 'mean' 'mean']

dc=dict(zip(df.columns,np.where(df.dtypes!='object','mean','first')))
dc
#{'Var1': 'mean', 'Var2': 'mean', 'Var3': 'mean', 'Var4': 'first', 'Var5': 'mean', 'Var6': 'mean'}
```

*To group by two rows*:

You can use `groupby`  with argument `df.index//2` to slice the dataframe in every two rows, and after that, use `agg` with the dictionary created before

```
df.index//2
#Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int64')

df.groupby(df.index//2).agg(dc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas 1.1 supports Null values in the groupby indexes :

```
columns = df.columns[:4].tolist()
df.groupby(columns, dropna=False, sort=False).agg("mean")

                                Var5    Var6
Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4        
1        2       NaN    string   101    201
                 5.0    0.5     1001    2001
```